# Snowflake - Connector issue with Python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to connect Snowflake using python connector `snowflake.connector`.

error:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 250003: Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://efa44011.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=306f23d5-8367-4f0c-a2ff-eebeaddc60d2&databaseName=SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA&schemaName=TPCH_SF1000&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH&request_guid=1f40e88e-610b-430a-adb5-52c8baed6dbc
```

Complete Code :

```
import snowflake.connector
print("Connecting...")
con = snowflake.connector.connect(
    user='XXXXXXXX',
    password='XXXXXXX',
    account = 'efa44011',
    warehouse = 'COMPUTE_WH',
    database = 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA',
    schema = 'TPCH_SF1000'
    )



con.cursor().execute("USE WAREHOUSE " +'COMPUTE_WH')
con.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE " + 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA')

cs = con.cursor()
try:
    cs.execute("SELECT current_version()")
    one_row = cs.fetchone()
    print(one_row[0])
finally:
    cs.close()
con.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked the account and confirmed that efa44011.snowflakecomputing.com is correct, so you are using the correct account params.  What sort of host are you running python on?  Your desktop, maybe an ec2 instance?

Can you try from a command prompt to see if the following works?

curl -k -v https://efa44011.snowflakecomputing.com

Comment: Hi , I got below response, It seems firewall issue . So how to pass the proxy in the parameter

Comment: 1>You are accessing the Internet via an PAN INTERNET FW. Only Office 365 Traffic is allowed through this Firewall, Check your browser Proxy Settings  </h1>
<p>C

Answer (score 2):

It might be the case that your account parameter is not correct.

Account information typically has the following structure depending on the region and cloud platform where your account is hosted:

```
account
account.region_id
account.region_id.platform
```

For example:

```
efa44011
efa44011.us-east-1
efa44011.east-us-2.azure
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the account URL appeared in the error is correct:
https://efa44011.snowflakecomputing.com:443

If not you have mention the incorrect account name in connection parameters.

Hope this might help!